# Moved files and now I am receiving a parsing error in vqmod for opencart

Tags: ssl-certificate, web-hosting, opencart

My client is using Yahoo web hosting (ugh) and in order to have an SSL certificate on their servers, you have to create a folder and move all the files you want to be secure to this folder. I had all of the `OpenCart` files in a folder called shop, so I just moved that entire folder there so I wouldn't have a ton of updating on links, etc.

Everything was working fine until I did this. Now I am receiving this when I try to view the shop or go to the admin panel:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_CLASS in /ssl/shop/vqmod/vqmod.php on line 6
```

The only code line 6 has is this:

```
final class VQMod {
```

Please help! I am trying to launch this site for my client either today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your file hasn't been uploaded correctly or you're running on an old version of PHP (PHP 4)

Comment: I did, however, find another person with a similar issue who posted about this saying that they just uploaded another copy of this same file and it fixed it. I will try that, too.

Comment: Then yeah I'd recommend uploading a fresh copy (download the latest version if you haven't already got it which is 2.2.0 currently)